# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (300) to match target batch_size (100)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, kaggle

I am trying to run RNN with COVID19+PNEUMONIA+NORMAL Chest X-Ray Image Dataset from Kaggle but getting an error like Expected input batch_size (300) to match target batch_size (100). I am running the model with pytorch and in kaggle environment.

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((256, 256)),  # Resize images to a common size
    transforms.ToTensor()
])


dataset = ImageFolder(root='/kaggle/input/covid-pneumonia-normal-chest-xray-images', transform=transform)



labels = np.array(dataset.targets)
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
train_idx, test_idx = next(sss.split(np.zeros(len(labels)), labels))

train_idx, val_idx = next(sss.split(train_idx, labels[train_idx]))


train_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, train_idx)
val_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, val_idx)
test_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, test_idx)


# Hyperparameters
sequence_length = 256
input_size = 256
hidden_size = 128
num_layers = 2
num_classes= 3
batch_size = 100
num_iters = 1200
learning_rate = 0.01  # More power so we can learn faster! previously it was 0.001

# Device
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")





num_epochs = num_iters / (len(train_dataset) / batch_size)
num_epochs = int(num_epochs)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           shuffle=True)   # It's better to shuffle the whole training dataset!

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False)

val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=val_dataset,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False)


torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42) if torch.cuda.is_available() else None
np.random.seed(42)


class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size= hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True) # For uni Directional RNN

        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes) #For uni Directional


    def forward(self, x):
        # set initial hidden and cell states
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device) #For uni Directional



        #Forward Propagation
        out, _  = self.rnn(x,h0)
        #out, _  = self.lstm(x,(h0,c0)) #out: tensor of shape (batch size, seq_length, hidden_size)
        # Decode the hidden state of the last time step
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out


model = RNN( input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes)
# To enable GPU
model.to(device)


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)



iter = 0
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

        images = images.reshape(-1, sequence_length, input_size).to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        outputs = model(images)

        # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters
        loss.backward()

        # Updating parameters
        optimizer.step()

        iter += 1

        if iter % 300 == 0:
            # Calculate Accuracy
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Iterate through test dataset
            for images, labels in test_loader:

                images = images.reshape(-1, sequence_length, input_size).to(device)

                # Forward pass only to get logits/output
                outputs = model(images)

                # Get predictions from the maximum value
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)

                # Total number of labels
                total += labels.size(0)


                # Total correct predictions
                if torch.cuda.is_available():
                    correct += (predicted.cpu() == labels.cpu()).sum()
                else:
                    correct += (predicted == labels).sum()

            accuracy = 100 * correct.item() / total

            # Print Loss
            print('Iteration: {}. Loss: {}. Accuracy: {}'.format(iter, loss.i
```

Getting error in this line : loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (300) to match target batch_size (100).

Comment: I think you should check the shape of `images` at this line `images = images.reshape(-1, sequence_length, input_size).to(device)`. Because you used `reshape` and I think it affects the shape of the output